# Need to add/remove group of options and display them as rows

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, table

I am creating a plugin which has 5 textbox for options. What I need to do is to treat these 5 options as 1 item, and being able to add more items.

I've always worked with static hardcoded options for my wordpress plugins, so I am not sure how to do this, but I will try to do my best to explain myself.

I want to have a table similar to the posts table, then I want to be able to add/remove rows. Each row will be one "item" containing the 5 options.

**Does someone knows a plugin that works similar to this so I can check it out? (if it also uses ajax that would be awesome)**

My main problem is I am not sure how to save/retrieve the multiple rows because I always hardcoded my option names on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a plugin to point you to off the top of my head, but my general suggestion is this: Store the relevant plugin settings in a *single* option, as an array. The crux of the reasoning here is that you're just adding items to a single array, which is auto-keyed, so you can add or subtract at will, without worrying about naming.

In practice, this means the following:

- Build your markup so that the textboxes have the `name` attribute of a shared array, eg

  ```
  <input name="my_textboxes[]" />
  <input name="my_textboxes[]" />
  ```
- When saving with AJAX, make sure you send the whole `my_textboxes` array as payload
- Your callback for saving the settings can then be straightforward. Since the *entire* my_textboxes array gets sent on every save, you can just save the whole shebang to the options table, overwriting previous settings:

  ```
  $my_textboxes = $_POST['my_textboxes'];
  update_option( 'my_plugin_textboxes', $my_textboxes );
  ```

  Of course, you may want to loop over the value passed by `$_POST['my_textboxes']` and do some sort of validation (check for duplicates, stuff like that).
- When you're building the markup on page load, you'll just do a foreach loop:

  ```
  $my_textboxes = get_option( 'my_plugin_textboxes' );
  foreach( $my_textboxes as $key => $tb ) {
      echo '<input type="text" name="my_textboxes[]" value="' . esc_attr( $tb ) . '" />';
  }
  ```

Comment: I found the plugin wp-testimonials, which uses a separated database for the testimonials, I like that and I think im going to do that. Thanks a lot anyway.